# How to bind the input field with vuejs by using template

Tags: vue.js

I am a new at [Vuejs](http://vuejs.org/)

In the below code I have used 2 instances of template , now I want to calculate the final outcome.I have tried but it didn't work. If anyone know then please help me.

**html**

```
<pre>

<template id="input-template">

    <label for="{{name}}">{{label | capitalize}}</label>
    <input type="text" id="{{name}}" class="form-control" name="{{name}}" v-model="name"/>

</template>

<form >
    <input_box label="quantity" name="quantity" ></input_box>
    <input_box label="price" name="price" ></input_box>
  {{totalprice}}
</form>
```

**js**

```
<script>
new Vue({
    el:'body',
    data:{
        message:'Hello world '
    },
    components:{
        input_box:{
            template:'#input-template',
            props:['name','label'],
            data:function(){
                return {name:''};
            },
            computed:{
                totalprice:function(){
                    return this.price * this.quantity;
                }

            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your defined data does not contain `price` and `quantity`

```js
new Vue({
    el:'body',
    data:{
        message:'Hello world ',
      price: 0,
      quantity: 0
    },
  //...
}
```

2. If you want value changes from the component's props to sync to the parent instance's data, you have to use the `.sync` modifier

```html
<form >
    <input_box label="quantity" name.sync="quantity" ></input_box>
    <input_box label="price" name.sync="price" ></input_box>
  {{totalprice}}
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have tried it but it didn't work...... i want to give v-model dynamicaly data..
like v-model="{{name}}"
so that i don't have to manually give v-model to every input field...
and to easily compute data